# Android Navigation Fragment background is black without setting

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

First in my Android Stuidio, it look like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMtgu.png)

But in my Android Phone, it look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAEUi.jpg)

When I turn to task List, it look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2VfB.jpg)

Here are the themes.xml code:

*themes.xml*

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Theme.ShareChargingPile2.Fullscreen" parent="Theme.ShareChargingPile2">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">
            @style/Widget.Theme.ShareChargingPile2.ActionBar.Fullscreen
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.ShareChargingPile2.FullscreenContainer" parent="">
        <item name="fullscreenBackgroundColor">@color/light_blue_600</item>
        <item name="fullscreenTextColor">@color/light_blue_A200</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Question: Why the background of my application is black? And how to fix this?**

**Solved**
In the themes.xml

```xml
    <style name="Theme.ShareChargingPile2.Fullscreen" parent="Theme.ShareChargingPile2">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">
            @style/Widget.Theme.ShareChargingPile2.ActionBar.Fullscreen
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

the windowBackground is @null.
I change to @color/white. The problem solved

```xml
<style name="Theme.ShareChargingPile2.Fullscreen" parent="Theme.ShareChargingPile2">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">
            @style/Widget.Theme.ShareChargingPile2.ActionBar.Fullscreen
        </item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: maybe your phone dark mode is on

Answer (score 0):

your phone dark mode is on or you can change in res->values->themes->themes.xml(night)change black to white or something else color.